# How to build floyd's triangle in python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a [Floyd's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_triangle) but output is not as expected.

Expected output

```
Please Enter the total Number of Rows  : 10
Floyd's Triangle
1  
2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9  10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  
37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  
46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
```

My code

```py
rows = int(input("Please Enter the total Number of Rows  : "))
number = 1

print("Floyd's Triangle")
i = 1
while(i <= rows):
    j = 1
    while(j <= i):        
        print(number, end = '')
        number = number + 1
        j = j + i
    i = i + 1
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the user input, the implementation is trivial:

```
def floyd(n):
    x = 1
    for r in range(n):
        print(*range(x, x := x + r + 1))

floyd(10)
```

**Output:**

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
```

Comment: apparently, not trivial enough. The aggregate variable is superfluous, try to get rid of it (and the ugly walrus construct at the same time).

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 mistakes that i've spotted in this code:

1. When printing one row, you should put space for the 'end' argument, therefore each number in a row would be separated by a space.

```py
print(number, end=' ')
```

2. **On line 11, you should've add 1 to the variable 'j'** instead of adding the value of the variable 'i', therefore the second loop won't be terminated the second times it run.

```py
j = j + 1
```

When you add the value of 'i' to the variable 'j', the second loop will be terminated at the second times it run because the value of 'j' is greater than 'i', it's obvious because 'j' is added by 'i' before. For practice, if you want to increase the value of the variable by one, use increment operator (++) instead, e.g. `i++`, `j++`, so you won't mistype it by other variable like this.